# Get the next due dates based on frequency of given dates

Tags: excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I have a sheet where I need to get the next expected due date based on the frequency and date of month

```
start date      end date        date of month   frequency (months)
2020-06-15      2050-01-05      15              6
```

hence 15-June & 15 Dec is expected and similarly for every dates.

[Here is the link of the sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BJyDjgz1HPK5uHUE3yjSLbBxDhZRXOze_WKOUT6ixiw/edit#gid=0)

I have tried with

```
=IF((MOD(MONTH(E17),D17)=MOD(MONTH(TODAY()),D17))*(DAY(E17)>=DAY(TODAY()))*(E17>=TODAY()),(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY()),DAY(E17))),TEXT(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY()),DAY(E17)),"mmm"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try:

```
=QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(EOMONTH(
if(true,EOMONTH(A2,D2-1)+C2,         "first pay date"),
SEQUENCE(
if(true,int(DATEDIF(A2,B2,"M")/D2),  "number of payments")
,1,-1,D2))+C2),"select Col1 where Col1 >= date '"&text(today(),"yyy-mm-dd")&"' limit 1")
```

The answer is based on [the other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65221589/5372400), mede before.

Extra logic: `query` lets you select the nearest date from the sequence of dates.

Comment: Works like charm!. Thanks Max

Answer (score 4):

I went a step further and defined a list of all payments until the end

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16l8TDFtuD1VWdXylAXHpQUiH1WiA51EQ49f3RCcZdHA/copy

[image]

A2 - start date
B2 - end date
F2 - expected due date
D2 - frequency

First I define first payment (G2):

```
=if(day(today())>=day(F2),
eomonth(F2,D2-1)+day(F2),
F2)
```

Then I check how many more payments should be made (H2)

```
=int(DATEDIF(A2,B2,"M")/D2)
```

Finally I define next payments (I2:I):

```
=ArrayFormula(edate(G2,sequence(H2+
                                        if(day(F2)>day(B2),-1,0)
                                     ,1,D2,D2)))
```

Comment: Nice explanation. I didn't know the `edate` function.

Comment: Thanks but I dont need an array of results. I just need the upcoming date utill the system date is arrived.